# Loading Generic view from UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view

Here is my problem : 
I created a `.xib` with some label. I created a `UITableViewController` like this :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
     dataToShow = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"cave",@"garage",nil];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [dataToShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

The `numberOfSectionInTableView` and `numberOfRowInSection` are filled correctly, when running the programe the list shows as it should. I would like now, depending on which row the user click in the table view, to load the xib i created and fill the labels with text. Is that possible and if it is, how do I pull it off ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    yourNextViewController *nextViewXib = [[yourNextViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"yourNextViewController" bundle:nil];
     nextViewXib.yourLable.text=[dataToShow objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewXib animated:YES];
    [nextViewXib release];
}
```

Comment: Im trying that at the moment, I got what you did, this should do what I need. Thanks

Comment: here just property, synthesize the UILable for Assign value to Lable.. otherwise use string with property, synthesize to pass the value..

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

 NSLog(@"selected row:%d",indexPath.row);
}

 //in this mathod you get will row is calling..
```